# Aplicacion Web deja de funcionar si cambio el HTML

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

tengo una aplicacion web que es un login que trabaja con firebase. Cuando uso el primer HTML la aplicacion realiza todo correctamente, pero cuando le aplico CSS y cambio al segundo ya no lo hace. Como se que es el HTML? Bueno, estuve probando con otros archivos y cambiando el javascript entre ellos y todo funciona bien, pero cuando cambia el html todo deja de funcionar. Que podria ser? Muchas gracias!

Primer HTML (Funciona sin problemas):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Login Firebase</title>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="login.js"></script>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Formulario</h1>
    <div id="formContainer">
        <div id="header"> </div>

        <input type="email" placeholder="email" id="email" />
        <input type="pass" placeholder="contrasena" id="pass" />

        <button onclick="signUp()" id="sigUp">Registrarse</button>
        <button onclick="signIn()" id="sigUp">Iniciar Sesion</button>
        <button onclick="signOut()" id="sigUp">Salir</button>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Segundo HTML (Con el cual no funciona):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Firebase 2</title>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="login.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login-box">
        <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo del Login">
        <h1>Inicio de Sesion</h1>
        <form>
            <!-- Email -->
            <label for="email">Correo Electronico</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Inserte su correo electronico" id="email"/>
            <!-- Contraseña -->
            <label for="pass">Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Inserte su contraseña" id="pass"/>

            <input type="submit" onclick="signIn()" id="signIn" value="Iniciar Sesion">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" onclick="signOut()" id="sigUp" value="Salir">
            <!--En caso que presione este link que envie un mail-->
            <a href="mailto:xxxxxxxxxxxxx">Contactar con el administrador</a><br>
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript (Informacion de keys eliminada):

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = firebase.auth();

//Funcion de Registro de Usuario 
function signUp(){
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var password = document.getElementById("pass");
        
    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value); //Hacemos el registro
    promise.catch(e => alert(e.message)); 
        
    alert("Signed Up");
}

//Funcion de inicio de sesion 
function signIn(){
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var password = document.getElementById("pass");
        
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
    promise.catch(e => alert(e.message));
    
    alert("Sign In" + email.value)

    
}

//Funcion para salir de la sesion 
function signOut(){ 
    auth.signOut();
    alert("Signed Out");   
}

//Funcion que una vez logeado nos permite llevar al usuario a otra pagina distinta donde visualizar el resto de cosas.
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user){     
    if(user){   
        var email = user.email;
        alert("Active User " + email);      
        //Take user to a different or home page
        //is signed in    
    }else{
        
        alert("No Active User");
        //no user is signed in, aca estaria si se sale
    }  
});
```

Comment: Creo que el javascript es necesario porque puede contener referencias a algún `id` que hayas quitado, por ejemplo `id="formContainer"` está en el primer html pero no en el segundo. Asegurate antes de publicarlo que no tengas información privada como claves, tokens, etc

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @PabloGutiérrez , ahi agregue el codigo de js. Si no me equivoco en ningun momento hago referencia a ese id, por lo tanto tengo entendido que no debiera haber problemas. Muchas gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema inicial está en el tipo que asignaste a los botones `<input type="submit"...` que ya tiene una funcionalidad predeterminada en el evento click y es la de enviar el formulario al servidor. Aunque hay forma de impedir o anular esa funcionalidad, no creo que tenga sentido en este caso porque puedes utilizar `<input type="button"...`

Por otra parte, al cambiar el tipo a `<input type="button"...`, también tienes que cambiar el `id="signIn"` del botón `Iniciar sesión` porque al llamarlo igual que la función `signIn()` creas un conflicto que provoca el error *...signIn is not a function....*

En el siguiente ejemplo omito parte del código para mantener el foco en el área de interés.

```
...
<form>

...

<input type="button" onclick="signIn()" id="idDistintoAlNombreDeLaFuncion" value="Iniciar Sesion">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="signOut()" id="sigUp" value="Salir">

....
```

En otro orden de ideas, te recuerdo que **no** deberías colocar información privada en el código de la aplicación y mucho menos en la que se ejecuta del lado del cliente.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, era exactamente eso, no se como no lo pense! Saludos!